# Error in pygame simulation "OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError"

Tags: python, pygame, physics

I'm trying to run this code in python, I already have the PyOpenGL library and the pygame library. It's a simulation to show the intermediate axis theorem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Intermediate Axis Theorem Simulator
# Author: Franco Barpp Gomes (https://github.com/Hyodar)

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Imported modules
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

import pygame.locals as pygl
import pygame

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

from utils.constants import WINDOW_SIZE
from utils.constants import NUM_FRAMES

from utils.classes.Screen import Screen
from utils.classes.World import World
from utils.classes.Tbar import Tbar

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


def main():

    print('[*] Creating pygame display...')
    pygame.init()
    display = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE, pygl.DOUBLEBUF | pygl.OPENGL)

    world = World()
    tbar = Tbar()
    world.add_object(tbar)

    screen = Screen(display=display, tbar=tbar)

    print('[*] Initializing scene...')
    world.init_scene()

    frame = 0
    paused = False

    print('[*] Starting pygame loop...')
    while frame < NUM_FRAMES:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print('[*] Quit event detected. Stopping pygame...')
                pygame.quit()
                exit(0)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    paused = not paused
                    if paused:
                        screen.show_paused_message()

        if not paused:
            world.clear()
            world.render()
            screen.render()

            frame += 1

            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.time.wait(10)

    print('[*] Simulation finished successfully')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

BUT, now I get this error,

```
[*] Creating pygame display...
[*] Initializing scene...
2020-08-13 20:41:59.869 python3[22970:759075] GLUT Warning: glutInit being called a second time.
[*] Starting pygame loop...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main.py", line 76, in <module>
    main()
  File "src/main.py", line 64, in main
    world.render()
  File "/Users/silviaar/python_projects/intermediate-axis-theorem-master/src/utils/classes/World.py", line 71, in render
    obj.render()
  File "/Users/silviaar/python_projects/intermediate-axis-theorem-master/src/utils/classes/Tbar.py", line 86, in render
    self.handle.render(self.cm, self.handle_relpos)
  File "/Users/silviaar/python_projects/intermediate-axis-theorem-master/src/utils/classes/Cylinder.py", line 56, in render
glutWireCylinder(self.radius, self.height, self.slices, self.stacks)
  File "/Users/silviaar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 407, in __call__
    self.__name__, self.__name__,
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutWireCylinder, check for bool(glutWireCylinder) before calli
ng
```

Not sure what's wrong, first the problem was that I had not install pygame, then OpenGL, but now I get this error and I can't find de function "glutWireCylinder"
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to run the same code, and so far I've ran into a few issues with FreeGLUT. If you're trying to run it on Windows as I am, then maybe you're running into the same initial issue that I had. From what I've read, the PyOpenGL package is missing a few things from FreeGLUT for Windows. The fix I found was to uninstall the OpenGL packages I had and pip install this custom one here:

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl)

It has all the extra things you need. The alternative is to track down dll files and place them in the right directories, but just reinstalling was easier and seems to work fine. Hopefully that's the issue you're having!
Currently when I run it I'm getting this error:

```
glutWireCylinder(self.radius, self.height, self.slices, self.stacks)
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000001C
```

I've contacted the author of the code on github and he said apparently there are issues running it on Windows, but that it works fine on Linux.
Let me know if reinstalling things helped, I'll let you know if I get the code running!

Update: After talking with the author of the code, he's removed all GLUT dependencies and now it seems to be working perfectly. Just re-download the code from the github link:

https://github.com/Hyodar/intermediate-axis-theorem

and it should work fine now!

Comment: Perfect, no problem!